# How to check how well linear regression model is fitted to data?

Tags: r

I have a small dataset, and a model which according to my calculations should fit the data pretty well (it was calculated manually, not with R), but I want to check exactly how well it fits to data. So is there a way to input my model in R (not make R fit the model) and check how well it fits the data?

I don't know if it matters but my modeling function is f(x)= -6.65x^2 - 23.28x - 16.85.
My dataset are just two vectors with 7 values each.

If someone knows a function that does this please help

Comment: This is impossible to know without the errors. If it's just 7 variables why don;t you just run it in R and it can give you heaps of info.

Comment: Can you add your dataset and your code to your question? You can use dput(data). What do you want to do? Do you want to manually verify if your regression model fits well? Please add these information if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have data for `x` and the observed values `y`, you will have to create a vector that stores all the predicted `y_hat(x)` and then use the metric that you want to use to evaluate the model.

Let´s say you have the following table:

```
>>> df
   y   x
  23   5
 998  12
 121  52
  57   3
```

The next step would be to add a column called `y_pred`:

```
df$y_pred = (df$x * df$x) - (df$x * 23.28) - 16.85
```

You now have `y_pred` stored in `df$y_pred`, so all you need to do is compare `df$y` against `df$y_pred` (you didn't specify how you want to do this).

For example, you could make a scatter plot of `df$x` and `df$y` and draw the line `df$y_pred` over it. I recommend using `ggplot` for this.
Otherwise, you can get the squared errors by doing `df$err_squared <- (df$y - df$y_pred)^2`. To get the sum, just try `sum(df$err_squared)`.